# How does SQL Server decide which "where" statement to use?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this piece of SQL, and I want to make it use the first valid when statement. But it just takes the one with most results :( I thought of making it put in one of the statements if fx. @afdeling is null. Just ask if you don't understand what I just wrote :)

```
DECLARE
    @email VARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @afdeling VARCHAR(MAX) = '20',
    @FRAN varchar(MAX) = 'V',
    @Interval int = -10;


SELECT        CASE WHEN BI.dbo.tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMAktion LIKE '%Bodyshop' THEN ' - Skadet' ELSE '' END AS Expr1, CASE WHEN BI.dbo.Z09newst.CHASSIS IS NULL THEN '' ELSE BI.dbo.Z09newst.CHASSIS END AS Expr2, 
                         CASE WHEN BI.dbo.Z09newst.[DESC] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE BI.dbo.Z09newst.[DESC] END AS Expr3, CASE WHEN BI.dbo.Z09newst.COMM IS NULL THEN '' ELSE BI.dbo.Z09newst.COMM END AS Expr4, 
                         CASE WHEN BI.dbo.tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMStockNum IS NULL THEN '' ELSE BI.dbo.tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMStockNum END AS Expr5, CASE WHEN BI.dbo.Z02targt.FULLNAME IS NULL 
                         THEN '' ELSE BI.dbo.Z02targt.FULLNAME END AS Expr6, CASE WHEN BI.dbo.tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMDepartment IS NULL THEN '' ELSE BI.dbo.tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMDepartment END AS Expr7, 
                         CASE WHEN Z06users.USERNAME IS NULL THEN '' ELSE Z06users.USERNAME END AS Expr8,
                         CASE WHEN z09newst.LOCN IS null then '' else z09newst.LOCN END 
FROM            Z09newst LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Z06users ON Z09newst.EXEC1 = Z06users.ASP LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Z02targt ON Z09newst.TARMAGIC = Z02targt.MAGIC RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         tblVognFlytningModtagelse ON Z09newst.STOCKNUM = 'N' + tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMStockNum
WHERE                   ((DATEADD(HOUR, @Interval, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMDato) AND (tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMDepartment = @afdeling) AND (Z09newst.FRAN = @FRAN)) OR
                        (DATEADD(HOUR, @Interval, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMDato) AND (Z09newst.FRAN = @FRAN) OR 
                        (DATEADD(HOUR, @Interval, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMDato) AND (tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMDepartment = @afdeling)
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN combined with RIGHT JOIN... I'd never dare to try such thing.

Comment: You know what, if one of the var is null, itll take the other one with the var in that is true... Im just stupid lmao

Comment: Your `where` clause looks like: (1) it is missing some parentheses to group the conditions (`and`/`or` confusion) and (b) it should be refactored to simplify it (`(DATEADD(HOUR, @Interval, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMDato)` is always required),

Answer (score 0):

You could try using NULL instead of ''.  Then COALESCE, which takes the first non-NULL value.

You can even remove the now redundant CASE statements. Which were just null-checkers

```
SELECT COALESCE(Expr1,Expr2,Expr3,....,'')
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN BI.dbo.tblVognFlytningModtagelse.VFMAktion LIKE '%Bodyshop' THEN ' - Skadet' ELSE NULL END AS Expr1,
        BI.dbo.Z09newst.CHASSIS AS Expr2, 
        BI.dbo.Z09newst.[DESC] AS Expr3,
        ....
    FROM ....
    WHERE ....
)
```